# Word for reversed order in causality

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for taking effect before something happened? like in time travel?

i.e. Because I killed my grandpa, I ****ly became non existent.

Comment: The word that fits the sample sentence is _paradoxically_ but it isn't a word meaning "reversed order in causality".

Comment: https://youtu.be/zeIsxXDyjlc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Retroactively" could be the word you are looking for.

- Because I killed my grandpa, I retroactively became non existent.

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retroactive) extending in scope or effect to a prior time or to conditions that existed or originated in the past

This is a word used extensively in the domain of administration but the examples below show that it is also used more generally.

- [Time and Cause: Essays presented to Richard Taylor](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22retroactively%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) 
  P. van Inwagen - 2013 - ‎
  Perhaps it might be thought, however, that (2F) is true and that that necessary condition can be satisfied retroactively (i.e., met at ti by later being met at t2). There are two objections to this. First, a fatalist cannot accept this consistently with his
- [Promised Bodies: Time, Language, and Corporeality in …](https://books.google.fr/books?id=PZo4AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA85&dq=%22retroactively%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTsK6C9OnoAhUH8BoKHaQqDj8Q6AEIzQIwHA#v=onepage&q=%22retroactively%22&f=false) 
  Patricia Dailey - 2013 - 
  ... impenetrable—then is retranslated into the present, given the new ability to finally read and understand its message. The implanted past thus carries within it a futurity that can only be known and read retroactively. The latency of implantation

Comment: Thank you. I knew this word but couldn't come up with it.